# Probability that no digits in the same place value are repeated

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let S be the set of three-digit integers whose digits are from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Three
distinct numbers are chosen from S. What is the probability that no two of these three
numbers have the same hundreds, tens, or units digit?

My answer differs from the given answer,

There are a total of  $125C3$ sets of 3, 3 digit numbers. The number of sets of 3, 3-digit numbers such that it satisfies the condition is
$5*5*5 * 4*4*4 *3*3*3$ because 1 digit from the place value cannot be chosen again.

thus the answer is $144*6/1271$, but the official answer is $144/1271$, is there something i am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your answer is off by a factor of $6$, i.e. is off by a factor of $3!$.  In your numerator you have a clear order of the numbers in question... $5\cdot 5\cdot 5$ corresponds to having picked the hundreds digit of the **first** number, the tens digit of the **first** number, etc... but in the denominator there is no "first" "second" or "third" number, we had forgotten in what order they occurred since we picked them simultaneously.  You should instead have used $(5^3)\frac{3}{~}=(5^3)(5^3-1)(5^3-2)=1906500$ rather than $\binom{125}{3}$ for your sample space size if you wanted order to matter in numerator.

$\dfrac{(5\cdot 4\cdot 3)^3}{(5^3)\frac{3}{~}} = \dfrac{144}{1271}$